# Dyanmic Class Creation in Python: TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, class

Trying to take the header form a .csv file and use it to define a class in Python. The goal is to process all subsequent lines in the file as class objects. Using a for loop I’ve translated the header to generate the human readable elements of a class constructor. I’m getting this error:

TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I’ve viewed some posts about this error here on StackOverflow, but trying to better understand the issue in this use case. Here is a what I’m trying to accomplish:

```
with open ('fooFile.csv','r') as csvInputFile:
filereader = csv.reader(csvInputFile)
header = []
header.append(next(filereader))
def buildSelfStatements (header):
    classBuilder = []
    for x in trimHeader:
        classBuilder.append('self.'+x+'='+x)
    return classBuilder
actionableHeader = buildSelfStatements(header)

class fooList:
    def __init__(self):
        actionableHeader

fooInstance = fooList(next(filereader))
```

Per the answer below I also tried:

```
class fooList:
    def __init__(self, header):
        actionableHeader

fooInstance = fooList(next(filereader))
```

I get the error on the last line. I realize this may not be possible, but I am open to learning from why this can’t be done if anyone has insights.

Comment: The issue with your current code is that `fooList`'s `__init__` method only has `self` as an argument.  To fix, simply add another argument to it. However, why and how are you dynamically making your classes?

Comment: Thank you for this. This is my first post on SO so I appreciate your time and patience. I've learned a lot from this community and am dipping my toe in as a contributor for the first time. Per your suggestion I modified to: __class fooList: def __init__(self, header)_ This generates an object in memory, but then produces this error: __AttributeError: 'fooList' object has no attribute 'atributeNestedInActionableHeader'_

Comment: To answer your question I was thinking if I can generate the class from the header of a csv file, and then process all subsequent lines against the class, I would quickly have a set of class objects I can interrogate or convert to dictionaries. It came to mind it would be useful for a particular table... and now I'm just trying to complete the thought experiment as a matter of learning. I appreciate all replies and input. Thanks again.

Comment: This doesn't create a dynamic class at all. You are simply populating a list of `str` objects and assigning it to the global variable `actionableHeader`, then referencing that global variable inside your `__init__`, which does *nothing* (that line could be erased without affecting the semantics of your code). You likely want to use `exec` to dynamically execute a *class definition statement*, or use the `type` class object constructor (classes are just objects, like any other, e.g. `int`, `list` etc, `type` is the contructor, and you can think of class definitions as syntactic sugar for that).

Comment: Awesome. Many thanks. Just beginning to synthesize from basics I've learned so this is very helpful guidance. Thanks again!